# Height and Width of the UIbutton on a cell changes on Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 2 questions here.

**1.)** 
In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i have added the following code.

```
[cell.comB addTarget:self action:@selector(comBClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When the user clicks on the button in that cell the following method gets fired. However, the position of the `UIbutton` after clicking changes. The button slips down a bit. How can i prevent this ? When i debugged i noticed that the button position changes after executing `[((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];`
 line.

```
- (void) comBClick:(id) sender {

    if(c%2==0)

    {

        [((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        [((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    c=c+1;

}
```

**2.**

How can i find the `width` and `height` of a UIButton ?

UPDATE

I have got the following AutoLayout Warning, which i believe is the reason for the issue. Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to solve it ?

[image]

Comment: A `UIButton` is a `UIView`. Look at the `bounds` or `frame` property.

Comment: Use `sender.frame.size.width` and `sender.frame.size.height` to get width and height

Comment: have you verified the images are exactly the same size (as in, through inspector in Finder)? Slightly different sized images can make it appear as though the position of a view has changed

Comment: @LouisTur I have updated my post. I think there's an issue with Autolayout. Can you have a look.

Comment: you can resolve that warning by selecting the button and clicking on the "resolve autolayout issues" button on the lower right hand corner view pane. then, select "update frame" if the button is out of place and the constraints are correct, or "update constraints" if the button is in the right place and the constraints need to be updated. Idk if this will solve your problem though

Answer (score 0):

2)

This is the easiest way:

```
float widht = ((UIButton *)sender).bounds.size.width;
float height = ((UIButton *)sender).bounds.size.height
```

Comment: I like putting in a breakpoint when I know the view hierarchy is set and then using the UI browser. Then in the utilities pane it will show some of the view's information

Comment: Use `CGFloat`, not `float`.